# Reading material for Posets and Partitions.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, reference-request, order-theory, book-recommendation

I am currently pursuing a course on Discrete Mathematics(DM). The book that my instructor suggested is K.H.Rosen DM. But in today's lecture, he gave a very descriptive talk on POSETS, Lattices, Chains and Anti-Chains, and Partitions.
I tried to look up the topics in K.H.Rosen, Naive Set Theory, and Introductory Combinatorics but I did not find the relevant material in any of these.
I am just an UnderGraduate so rather than very specific books I would like to read texts that is sort of easy.
Could anyone suggest some?

Comment: Isn't this a better question for your instructor? He knows what he expects from you as well as the level of text that would be appropriate.

Comment: I meet him once a week and couldn't ask today. And he specifically said to not to pester him by mailing.

Comment: It is very difficult to help you because we don't know what level you are at or what your professor said that you don't understand. I recommend that you review your notes and ask specific questions about topics that are unclear.

Comment: A book on order theory could help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Introduction to Lattices and Order
Book by B. Davey and H. A Priestley